# Conditional formatting based on the content of a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Long story short: My boss has an Excel spreadsheet for calculating product prices. She has three columns to calculate different margins (so would contain a formula like =cost*.5 etc.), then adds to those values to determine final retail (so would be =column+500). She has her margin columns highlighted different colors and wanted to automatically highlight the final retail cell based on which margin column it references.

I'm sure there's a way of setting up the document from the start that makes this more intuitive, but short of restructuring her entire system, are there any formulas I could use in combination to return a format based on the content of the formula?

I immediately assumed to use "if cell contains specific text" and use the referenced column letter as the text, but excel reads the output for the formatting and not the formula, so I am stumped.

I was thinking somehow to use "isformula", but all the values are formulas just with different input.

Comment: You can use `FORMULATEXT` function to get the formula input text.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you made table of all the unique formulas that are used:

```
formula_test, rule,
=cost*0.5,1
=column+500,2
```

Then you could create conditional formatting rules by formula with one for each unique formula case.

`=VLOOKUP(FORMULATEXT(A1),$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE)=1`

`=VLOOKUP(FORMULATEXT(A1),$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE)=2`

Where A1 is the first cell in the range where you want the conditional formatting to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The missing link was "SEARCH":
=SEARCH("=Sum(J",FORMULATEXT(N2))

(J = the referenced margin column, N2 = first cell to apply the final retail formula)